# Global solution with json marshalling Play Framework 2

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, jackson, marshalling

is there any good solutions with Play 2 to get specific attributes of JSON according to annotations ? I would like to manage for my Objects something which is like my exemple. 
I do not want to code for each object multiples specific marshaller.

```
public class User extends Models{
    @useForJson("all")
    public Long id;

    @useForJson("parse3")
    public String email;

    @useForJson("parse1","parse2")
    public String firstName;

    @useForJson("parse3","parse2")
    public String lastName;

    @userForJson("none")
    public int age;

}
--------------->
User user = new User();
Json json1 = user.toJson("parser1") // id, firstName
Json json2 = user.toJson("parser2") // id, firstName, lastName
Json json3 = user.toJson("parser3") // id, email, lastnName
Json json4 = user.toJson() // id, email, firstName, lastName, age
```

Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to specify a parser for JSON but a serializer, that converts an object into JSON with only some of its properties. Play uses Jackson, so the solution is using jackson's *views* feature: `org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonView`

It will let you choose a class for each property, that will act just like the "parser1" string in your example. The usage of classes here is a disagreeable design choice, but that's the only way to do it as far as I know.

You can build some kind of hierarchy by extending other 'view' classes. Here's an example how to use it, you should probably find some better naming for the classes:

```
public class User extends Models {

    public static class All { }
    public static class View1 extends All { }
    public static class View2 extends View1 { }
    public static class View3 extends All { }

    @JsonView(All.class)
    public Long id;

    @JsonView(View1.class)
    public String email;

    @JsonView({View2.class, View3.class})
    public String name;

}
```

Properties without any `@JsonView` will be included in any view, so the `All` class could be omitted in the example.

The Play json api is an too abstract wrapper to support this, you have to use jackson directly. It also doesn't create a play Json object, but I'm sure that is somehow possible too. Take a look at the jackson api, there's probably some more elegant way to do this. Serialize an object like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SerializationConfig cfg = 
    objectMapper.copySerializationConfig().withView(User.View2.class); 
objectMapper.setSerializationConfig(cfg);
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

---

If you want something similar for parsing JSON data that actually only contains some properties, it might be easier to use `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties` and annotate your class like this to simply ignore properties that aren't included in the serialized data:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User extends Models {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: the call changes with play 2.2.x using the new jackson api. take a look at the documentation http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Comment: It seems in Play 2.4 you will be able to access Play's "own" ObjectMapper by calling  [play.libs.Json.mapper()](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.0-M1/framework/src/play-json/src/main/java/play/libs/Json.java#L32).